# htaccess map anything after /path to path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here's the scenario:

I have a site that uses various mod_rewrites to remove file extensions and the such. What I need now is to send any traffic to /path/something/something/ to /path/ but keeping the segmentation in place.

Here's my file, it's the last rule that's causing problems in that it's redirecting to /path rather than keeping the pathname and rendering /path

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*/)index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

#This is the problem child!
RewriteRule ^path/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /path [NC]
```

Thanks for any tips in advance!

Comment: Can you update your question to give explicit examples of how the request should look to Apache? It's not clear what is meant by "keeping the segmentation".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I stumbled across the solution through trial and error:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^path/(.*)$ path/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Probably should've mentioned the index.php in the question too!